# Validate aspx texbox through Javascript - undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to validate a aspx textbpx with Javascript and am getting following error when if statement is executed in Javascript:

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

The following is the function in JavaScript in aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction(var1)
 {
 if (document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value == "") 
 {
     alert("Please enter something");
     document.getElementByID("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").focus();
 }
 else
{
 alert("Text box has value");
}
}
</script>
```

Following is aspx:

```
<div id="Div1">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="myFunction('TextBox1')" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">TextBox Data</asp:TextBox>
```

I have tried, "ValueOf", "InnerText" also. I have also tried passing TextBox1 as avriable and still doesn't work.

Does anyone know why I am unable to access TextBox1 from JavaScript function???

Thank you

Comment: look at the source of your page in the browser and see if element `input` with `id="TextBox1"` is there

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. There isn't an input element, just a button and Textbox. The TextBox ID is TextBox1

Comment: When you run the web application, look at the html source of your page in the browser - right mouse click and choose "View source" or "View page source". Server-side `TextBox` control should become `input` html element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 if(document.getElementById('<%= yourtextboxid.ClientID%>').value != "")
     { 
       alert("has value!")
     } else {
      alert("please enter some thing");
      document.getElementById('<%= yourtextboxid.ClientID%>').focus();
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for response. This works, but only if I put it at the top of the function. If it is at the end, it fails. I have other objects that are created between the top and bottom of function. I am wondering if some of that code is causing this error. Anyway, thanks again. This site rocks.

Comment: @KentE :) This must work any where in the code. If its not working in the end than you must debug your code line by line.